# Matching rhyming words with currencies

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

- The left column forms four words that rhyme.
- The right column forms four currencies.
- Every image matches with exactly one image in the column opposite to it.

[image]

Find all the correct matching pairs from the given figure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rhyming words:

- > The **Bride** is Uma Thurman's role in [Kill Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bride_(Kill_Bill)).
- > A fifteen puzzles, where you must **slide** tiles.
- > **Glide** is the first released song by the Japanese band [Lily chou-Chou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lily_Chou-Chou), here depicted by the poster for the film [All About Lily Chou-Chou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_About_Lily_Chou-Chou).
- > "**Pride** and Prejudice" is a novel by [Jane Austen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Austen).

The currencies:

- > The full name of [King Alfonso XIII of Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfonso_XIII) is Alfonso León Fernando María Jaime Isidro Pascual Antonio de Borbón y Habsburgo-Lorena. The currency is the **Sierra-Leonean leone**.
- > Karim Benzema plays for (and in the picture wears the strip of) Real Madrid. The currency is the **Brazilian real**.
- > Sister Krone is a supporting charecter in the manga series [The Promised Neverland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Promised_Neverland). The currency is the **Danish krone**.
- > The [Man with No name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_with_No_Name) is a spaghetti western in the Dollars trilogy. The currency is the **US dollar**.

The matches:

> The four rhyming words have the suffix -ide in common and differ by their first two letters, **br**, **sl**, **gl** and **pr**. These two letters are valid [ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) country codes. The currencies are legal tender in the respective countries. So:
>
>  **br** Brazil — **real**
>  **sl** Sierra Leone — **leone**
>  **gl** Greenland — Danish **krone**
>  **pr** Puerto Rico — US **dollar**
>
>  So the correct matches are **1b**, **2a**, **3c** and **4d**.

Credit:

> My answers builds on Ed Murphy's, which identifies all the images. So thanks to him!

Answer (score 2):

> KB: 1 - Kill Bill; b - Karim Benzema

> Wordless: 2 - 15 puzzle; d - The Man with No Name

> AL: 3 - All About Lily Chou-Chou; a - Alfonso XIII of Spain

> Sisters: 4 - Jane Austen; c - Sister Krone, The Promised Neverland

Comment: nope, not what I was looking for. I have added a hint to the question now if that helps.

Comment: Okay, that suggests rot13(oevqr, fyvqr, naq cevqr) for 1, 2, and 4, but I'm drawing a blank on the rest of it.

Comment: rot13(Gur arjrfg uvag fhttrfgf Qnavfu/Abejrtvna xebar sbe P, naq Qbyynef sebz gur Qbyynef Gevybtl sebz Q. Pna'g trg gur bgure gjb gubhtu.)